# How to find if any of input fields in table (angular) are invalid as per used regex pattern

Tags: html, angular

I have the table used in angular application and for each input field, I'm checking for the regex pattern. Now I want to disable the button on same page, to see if any of the table input values were invalidated with regex. Just want to see if angular provides any such functionality. I know I can iterate over the whole object and write regex for each element and match and on basis of that disable the button,but this looks like overhead.

If there is any option I can use, please suggest

Update: Code Sample: Currently I have inValid method to do other validations, I want to add another function or way, which basically checks all table values for validity as per each regex. 
Input :

```
<div class="row">
<div class="col-sm-1" >
  <button [disabled]="isInvalid()" (click)="submit()" mat-raised- 
  button>Submit</button>
 </div>

<div class="container">
<div class="row"> 
<table class="center table table-bordered table-striped">
 <tbody> 
  <tr *ngFor="let element of dataArray; let i = index">
   <td>
     <input [(ngModel)]="element.name" class="form-control" type="text" 
     name="{{element.name}}" required pattern="^[A-Za-z \-\\d]{2,100}$" 
     minlength="1" />
   </td>
    <td>
     <input [(ngModel)]="element.id" class="form-control" type="number" 
     name="{{element.id}}" pattern="[0-999]" 
     required/>
    </td>
  </tr>
 </tbody>
 </table>
 </div>
 </div>
```

I tried using ReactiveForm , FormGroup to do validations on each input element and wrapped table and whole page around form, but I was unable to enable the button. I faced couple of errors as well using ngModel and form , I don't want to change a lot in existing code, is there a way to work without using Form or a way to fix the warning and make it work. Thanks

Comment: update your question with what you have tried so far

Comment: @SudarshanaDayananda tried to iterate over the list with regex for each element in its typescript file, but it did add overhead in processing. Want to know if there is any other best way to handle such scenario. I'm new to angular or front end development, hoping to get suggestions.

Comment: Using ReactiveForms, you could wrap the table with a form and then assign a form control to each input, doing so will give you access to your inputs validation state. Furthermore, you could move your validation pattern to the formGroup definition for each one of your formControls.

Comment: @crdevdeu tried but didn't exactly work. posted more code and update.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
<form #myForm="ngForm">
  <input data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" 
  class="inputtr form-control" type="text" required pattern="^[A-Za-z\d]$" 
  />
  <button [disabled]="myForm.invalid"></button>
</form>
```

Comment: Thanks, i tried this, it works on my sample app, however on my main app where I want this to work , it doesn't enable the button if table data is valid. also get a warning "It looks like you're using ngModel on the same form field as formControl."   I tried solving this and use ReactiveForms with FormGroup validations, but didn't work.  My existing code does use ngModel and the table is being filled with clipboard and also user can edit/add/update the table rows.

Comment: Update the question section with more detailed code, not sure what I'm doing wrong.